# How to print logging from tweepy module to stdout

Tags: python, logging, tweepy, python-logging

I am using the following code to print all the logging:

```
rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(handler)
```

It works fine all the modules `urllib3, requests, oauthlib, matplotlib` that are used in my scripts except it does not print anything from the `tweepy` module. When I print all the loggers using:

```
loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
```

it outputs all the loggers from the other modules and:

```
<Logger tweepy.binder (WARNING)>, 
<Logger tweepy (WARNING)>
<Logger tweepy.auth (WARNING)>, 
<Logger tweepy.cache (WARNING)>, 
<Logger tweepy.streaming (WARNING)>
```

I expect to at least be getting a log from this in the tweepy module because I know I am connected:

```
class Stream:

    ....
    ....

    def on_connect(self):
    """This is called after successfully connecting to the streaming API.
    """
    log.info("Stream connected")
```

Comment: What version of Tweepy are you using?

Comment: @Harmon758 3.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy v3.10 has `on_connect` in `StreamListener`, and it does not log by default:
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/v3.10.0/tweepy/streaming.py#L35-L42

That `Stream.on_connect` code is from the development version on the master branch.

When streaming with v3.10, the only time Tweepy will use logging is when an unknown message type is received.

Comment: I was reading this: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
Seems to be a different version but I am not sure

Comment: The default branch is the master branch, i.e. https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/tree/master. https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/tree/v3.10.0 is v3.10.